# How do I define the response match level to prevent a street level search

Tags: here-api

I am trying to geotag a number of Mexican towns/suburbs using the town/suburb name, the district, and the suburb. that is all i have available to me.

an example of this is:

```
El Pentagono,Tamaulipas,Aldama
(town)       (state)    (district)
```

This winds up as the following query:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?gen=9&jsonattributes=1&app_code=[app_code]&app_id=[app_id]&country=MX&responseattributes=parsedRequest&searchtext=El Pentagono,Tamaulipas,Aldama
```

which returns a street level match...
(edited highlights)

```
"relevance": 1,
"matchLevel": "street",
"matchQuality": {
"country": 1,
"state": 1,
"city": 1,
"street": [0.9]
"address": {
    "label": "Carretera a El Pentagono, 89670 Aldama, TAMPS, México",
    "country": "MEX",
    "state": "TAMPS",
    "city": "Aldama",
    "street": "Carretera a El Pentagono",
    "postalCode": "89670",
```

so it has matched on a street, rather than the town/suburb of El Pentagono. So how do I tell the API... "no way Jose, give me a town/suburb on El Pentagono, and leave it at that. Don't go looking at streets".

Any help/advice would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to get the admin hierarchy for a location is to call the Reverse Geocoder with `mode=retrieveAreas` by using the coordinates you got from the Forward Geocoder response.

> retrieveAreas - Retrieve the administrative area information for the
>   position provided in the request

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html for details.

Comment: Theoretically, that might work. but where the town returned on the forward lookup is incorrect (ie: the API has returned a street name match in a different town or a different state), then the lat/long will be wrong, and the reverse lookup will return the incorrect state.

I am looking to do this for approximately 85,000 locations, so its unlikely such errors will be picked up easily, and will corrupt our final dataset.

Comment: Oh hang on... i just reread your response...

As you can see in my original post above, my query contains the town, state and area. (El Pentagono,Tamaulipas,Aldama). So i already have the administrative areas. admin1 and admin2. The response is returning El Pentagono street in Aldama. I need the centroid for El Pentagono (the suburb). So i need the API to stop at the town/district level.

The lat long for Carretera a El Pentagono (El Pentagono) is different to the lat long for El Pentagono.

I can provide further examples if need be.